# Htaccess URL rewrite to Yii2 application

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following url structures in my Yii2 application

```
http://127.0.0.1/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin
http://127.0.0.1/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fpage2
http://127.0.0.1/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fsample
http://127.0.0.1/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fsignup
```

How can I convert that URL to something like

```
http://127.0.0.1/login.php
http://127.0.0.1/page2.php
http://127.0.0.1/sample.php
http://127.0.0.1/signup.php
```

I should remove `frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2F`

I tried like and it didn't work

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Force search engines to use http://127.0.0.1/frontend/web/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://127\.0\.0\.1/frontend/web/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://127.0.0.1/frontend/web/$1 [R=301,L]

# Specify search friendly URLs
RewriteRule ^login\.php$ /index.php?r=site%2Flogin [L]
```

I also tried like and it didn't work too.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2F([^\./]+) /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Do you want add `.php` suffix globally or just to `SiteController` actions?

Comment: @arogachev - Globally through htaccess

Comment: And you want to remove `site` just for `SiteController` actions, right?

Comment: @arogachev - No, don't want to see it in urls.

Answer (score 1):

No need to change `.htaccess` to achieve this. Adjust `urlManager` component.
Add this to your application config:

```
'components' => [
    'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true, // Cancel passing route in get 'r' paramater
        'showScriptName' => false, // Remove index.php from url
        'suffix' => '.php', // Add suffix to all routes (globally)
    ],
    // Compare requested urls to routes
    'rules' => [
        'login' => 'site/login',
        'page2' => 'site/page2',
        'sample' => 'site/sample',
        'signup' => 'site/signup',
    ],
],
```

As for removing controller part from all other routes - it violates key MVC concepts.

How you define to which controller requested action belongs in that case?

And what in case of actions with the same name?

For example: `http://127.0.0.1/create.php` - should it load `site/create` or `users/create`?

Also I don't sure if it's good practice, but you can write comparisons to all routes the same way with rules, but all action names should be unique.

Conclusion: you can modify urls to desired view as I mentioned above, but omitting controller names is only recommended for default controller (`SiteController`).

Official documentation:

- [UrlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html)
- [$enablePrettyUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$enablePrettyUrl-detail)
- [$showScriptName](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$showScriptName-detail)
- [$suffix](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$suffix-detail)
- [$rules](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$rules-detail)
- [Routing and URL Creation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)

Comment: Under `frontend/controllers/sitecontroller.php` in the `public function actions()` I did keep this code and it didn't help. Still I am unable to call other urls with `domain/login.php`

Comment: You should place it in application config as I mentioned above depending on your template (basic / advanced). `actions()` is used for completely different purposes.

Comment: I am using advanced application and under frontend > config > main.php within components I did paste your code and still I am unable to call as domain/login.php

Comment: Now, even `index.php?r=site%2Flogin` also displaying home page but not login page.